# Converting PromiseKit to Signal & SignalProducer

Tags: swift, promisekit, reactive-swift

I'm trying to convert a `Promise<T>` from [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) into a [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) `SignalProducer` but I'm having trouble coming up with it. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Currently I have:

```
extension SignalProducer {
    func from(promise: Promise<Value>) -> SignalProducer<Value, Error> {
        return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in
            promise.then {
                observer.send(value: $0)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }.`catch` { error in
                observer.send(error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to emulate rxjs' `fromPromise` method.

Comment: This is something that I have had trouble doing myself. it seems as though the nature of Promisekit is quite mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
extension SignalProducer where SignalProducer.Error: Swift.Error {

    static func from(promise: Promise<Value>) -> SignalProducer<Value, Error> {
        return SignalProducer { (observer: Observer<Value, Error>, disposable: Disposable) in
            promise.then { value -> () in
                observer.send(value: value)
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }.catch { (error: Swift.Error) -> Void in
                observer.send(error: error as! Error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```